# load an image from storage in android

Tags: android, imageview, local-storage

I am trying to load an image into an image view from a folder. I already have the name of the image and I want the user to select the location of the folder where the image is present.
I am selecting the folder using the following code

```
        binding.btnSelctFolder.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).also {
                it.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                startActivityForResult(it, 101)
            }
        }
```

For example, the image is `testImage.jpg` present in the folder `Downloads` so I want the user to select the folder `Downloads` and then the code should find the required image and load the image into the image view.

Note the name of the image is fetched from a json file so the user cannot choose the image directly

Can someone help me?
Thank You

Comment: If you read a bit about Storage Access Framework (there are many pages on stackoverflow tagged like that) you will soon find the code how to list the files in the choosen tree.

Comment: Why not let the user choose the image with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: How did testImage.jpg land in Downloads? If your app did it you would already have a nice uri and you were done.

Comment: The user can't choose the image directly because I am getting the name of the image from a a json file

Comment: ??? What does it matter where you got the name from?  If you can tell the user to select the Download folder then you can ask the user to select a file in the Download folder. If the image is present the user can select it.

Comment: Actually the app I am trying to make requires the user to select only the folder and the app should find the image. It is sure that the image is present in the correct folder